# Why Object class has no Thread methods

Tags: multithreading, object

Why Object Class having wait(),notify(),notifyAll() methods. We need to extend Thread or implement Runnable to give Thread like behavior to a class . So why dint made them as part of Any of Thread or

Comment: Nothing whatsoever to do with MySQL. What language *are* you talking about? Not a real question.

Answer (score 0):

An object is not inherently associated with a thread - it's essentially just some field values and a (sub)class identifier in the virtual machine's memory space. By default, an object is quite usable by all threads of a running Java application.